# ng-show / ng-hide stop working if placed inside a file included with ng-include

Tags: angularjs

I observed that when I include a template with the `ng-include` directive, `ng-show` and `ng-hide` don't seem to work.

***Note**: Tested in angularjs `1.0.4` and `1.0.5`*

---

### This Works

#### `template.html`

```
<table ng-init="changeable = null">
  <tr ng-repeat="(key, item) in items" ng-click="changeable = key">
    <td>
      <span ng-show="changeable != key">{{item.name}}</span>
      <input ng-hide="changeable != key" ng-model="item.name">
    </td>
    <td>
      <button ng-click="changeable = null">OK</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

### This does not work

#### `template.html`

```
<div ng-include src="'/changeable_table.html'"></div>
```

#### `changeable_table.html`

```
<table ng-init="changeable = null">
  <tr ng-repeat="(key, item) in items" ng-click="changeable = key">
    <td>
      <span ng-show="changeable != key">{{item.name}}</span>
      <input ng-hide="changeable != key" ng-model="item.name">
    </td>
    <td>
      <button ng-click="changeable = null">OK</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

### Update

after a while [github@pkozlowski-opensource](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2077#issuecomment-14226676) give me a link to the wiki that explains really good why is necesary this namespace, it's [The Nuances of Scope Prototypal Inheritance](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/The-Nuances-of-Scope-Prototypal-Inheritance)

Comment: But it [does work](http://embed.plnkr.co/tgF3U4qiElv7Kh30dum8). Btw, watch out for those nested ng-click bindings.

Comment: ng-click works fine but when click on the <tr> the input isn't show it. i'm using Chrome 24.0.1312.57 on Windows 8 64bits even your example wont works

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have 2 problems there:

1. Don't forget that `ng-repeat` creates a new scope for each entry and the way you're doing it, the `changeable` property will not be shared among all those scopes. Define your model correctly (example):

   ```
   <table ng-init="model = {}; model.changeable = null">
   ```

   And change all references to `changeable` to `model.changeable`.
2. The `ng-click` on the tr will override the `ng-click` on the button (when you click the button you also click on the tr). Move the tr `ng-click` to the span:

   ```
   <span ng-show="model.changeable != key" ng-click="model.changeable = key">{{item.name}}</span>
   ```

**plunker:** http://plnkr.co/edit/TTAUsPhqSq2rkF47EtNL?p=preview

Comment: Your response was similar to the response I got in the issues section from angularjs repository but better explained +1 for that. PS: don't worry about button, that was only for complete the example of functionality